# join based on two columns in R

Tags: sql, r, join, left-join, dplyr

suppose that we have 2 tables.

First table `A`:

```
name    x     y
  a     1     2
  b     3     4
  c     5     7
  d     8     7
  c     5     3
  b     5     4
```

Second table `B`:

```
name    z     w
  a     1     9
  b     3     5
  c     5     2
  d     8     1
  b     5     9
```

I wish to do `left join` on these 2 tables on `name` and `x` and `z`, i.e., `x` and `z` are basically the same but with different names. Therefore, the final table should look like:

```
name    x     y    w
  a     1     2    9
  b     3     4    5
  c     5     7    2
  d     8     7    1
  c     5     3    2
  b     5     4    9
```

Any idea on how to do that in `R` or `SQL`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'x' and 'w' are same.

Comment: If `x` and `w` are the same, why are they different in every row of your final table? Seems like you want to just join on `name`.

Comment: Sorry for that. I meant `x` and `z`.

Comment: read up on `merge`, this will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT A.NAME,A.X,B.Y.B.W FROM A INNER JOIN B 
   ON 
   A.X=B.Z
```

Comment: do you know how to do this in R?

Comment: The Below link will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you should probably add an equality condition for `NAME`s. Good link though, probably best to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL

```
select A.name, x, y, w
from A
join B
on A.name = B.name and x = z
```

In `dplyr` you'll need to rename B's `z` to `x`. `dplyr` will make sure any columns named the same in each are equal.

```
library(dplyr)
names(B)[which(names(B) == "z")] <- "x"
left_join(A, B)
```

You can do similar with base functions, see `?merge`.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "A"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "B"
ON "A".name = "B".name
AND x = w
```

In r:

Please enter

```
?merge
```

on the r command line to see the documentation for the `merge` function.

This should be something like what you're looking for:

```
merge(x=A, y=B, by.x = c("name","x"), by.y=c("name","w"), all.x=TRUE)
```